Why can't we use or export the express() instance in other modules / files instead of using Router() instance while segregating routes in Express
I've tried to created routes in other files by exporting the express app instance
const app = express() and
export default app, but I'm getting the 404 route not found error when I import app instance in another file; why is that? And why do we need to use Router() to segregate routes instead of just importing the app instance in other files / modules?
// ------ index.js ------
const express = require('express');
const port = process.env.PORT || '3001';
const app = express();
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Welcome to Home')
});
app.listen(port, () => console.log('app is running'));
module.exports = app

// ------ booksRoutes.js --------
const app = require('./index.js')
app.get('/books', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Welcome to the Library')
});



I would guess that it's because you first call listen and then add another route

You don't import booksRoutes.js anywhere

@Konrad It's possible to register express routes dynamically

@EstusFlask I though that op is using booksRoutes as main file but you are right. They wanted to import booksRoutes in the index.js not the other way around

This depends on where booksRoutes.js is imported. Currently it's not, so /books route isn't expected to exist. It should be imported in main entry point, but this would create circular dependency between booksRoutes.js and index.js that cannot be resolved.
In order for this to work, this would require to create a separate app.js module for app instance that would be imported in other modules that use it:
const app = express();
module.exports = app;

Router instances are used to modularize the hierarchy of routes and make it easier to develop and maintain.
